# Cursor returns empty when querying for particular column values, even though rows exist

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have implemented a custom SQLite database helper.  I have a table containing sms messages.  I query this table for entries from a particular phone number like so:

```
public Cursor getSmsForContact(String phoneNumber) throws SQLException {
    phoneNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(phoneNumber);
    Cursor cursor =
     db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_DATE,
            KEY_BODY,
            KEY_CONTACT,
            KEY_TYPE,
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_MESSAGE_STATE
    }, KEY_CONTACT + "=" + phoneNumber, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

This method works fine for numbers that do not have a "+" in the front (indicating a country code).  However, it always returns an empty cursor when `phoneNumber` has a "+" in the front.  I've verified that the `PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators()` method does not remove the "+" sign.  I've also verified that rows exist in the table which match the phone number which is being queried.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
}, KEY_CONTACT + "= ?" , new String[] {phoneNumber}, null, null, null);
```

Phone number is being interpreted as a number; you want it to be interpreted as a string

Comment: You are my hero! I knew it was something simple. Thanks.